# New to google app engine ! what to do next?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to develop some web apps using Google app engine. I had deployed a guest book application which was their in "gooleappengine" folder by changing its ID.and also was successful.This is simple one.But not getting how to develop complex web apps. Can anyone please suggest me any good Tutarial or example codes Or any books to refer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some good resources :

Articles :

- Official documentation :
  http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/overview.html
- Nick Johnson's blog :
  http://blog.notdot.net
- Google App Engine articles :
  http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/

Code examples :

- Google App Engine Cookbook :
  http://appengine-cookbook.appspot.com/
- Github repositories : http://github.com/search?type=Repositories&language=python&q=appengine
- Google Project Hosting projects : http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label%3Apython+label%3AAppEngine&btn=Search+projects

Answer (score 1):

Typically when I end up doing something more than a trivial demo I need a reason.  Figure out something you want to make and stumble through it, learning as you go until it's working.

I'd use the google app engine community as a place to get questions answered, they're pretty good for that.

As a first app, I'd just have a goal that you're working towards and start asking the community "how do I do this...?"